# Finding Key from Hashmap using Values(with space)

Tags: java, hashmap

Here i am trying to get key from value in Hashmap, but whenever i am trying "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", it should return "GBR". It is showing me "No Records Found". How to solve this. Any help will be appreciated.

(Here if you will enter country code then it will return country name and if you will enter country NAME then it will return country CODE.)

```
public class AppliedWithCS_1 {

public static Object getKeyFromValue(HashMap hashMap, Object value) {
for (Object o : hashMap.keySet()) {
  if (hashMap.get(o).equals(value)) {
    return o;
  }
}
return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("AFG","Afghanistan");
    hashMap.put("GBR","United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland");
    hashMap.put("IDN","Indonesia");
    hashMap.put("IND","India");
    System.err.println("Enter Country Code or Country Name=");
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1=scanner.next();
    if(s1.length()>3&&hashMap.containsValue(s1))
    {
        System.out.println(getKeyFromValue(hashMap,s1));
    }
    else if(hashMap.containsKey(s1))
        System.err.println(hashMap.get(s1));
    else
        System.err.println("No Records Found");
}
}
```

Output:

```
   Enter Country Code or Country Name=
   Afghanistan
   AFG

   Enter Country Code or Country Name=
   United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland
   No Records Found
```

Comment: You've set the key to be "GBR". If the user enters "GBR", they will see the UK printed. If you want to do it the other way round, you need a map where UK is the key, and GBR is the value.

Comment: No Sir it is working perfectly but when i enters "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland". Then its not working. @erickson

Comment: Try `System.err.println("No Records Found for "  + s1);` and things will be more clear

Comment: Ah, I see. I apologize for not reading the code carefully. You should ignore my previous comment.

Comment: No problem Sir, Thank You for your valuable time..@erickson

Answer (score 2):

You have to use     `String s1 = scanner.nextLine();`, instead of  `String s1 = scanner.next();`

And it'll work and output  : `GBR`

---

Because [`next()` (from the doc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) will use by default, spaces as delimiter so it takes only the forst word

In your case after `String s1 = scanner.next();`, `s1` was juste `United`

Comment: @Shalin you're welcome, you can think about accept the answer so ;)

Comment: Q: " How do I debug my code?" A: "Post a question on SO."